# AWS API JavaScript SDK CORS errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, sdk, cors, aws-media-live

I am trying to connect to AWS API using the JavaScript SDK.  In particular, I need to connect to MediaLive services, but keep getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://medialive.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/inputSecurityGroups/123456' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have enabled AWSElementalMediaLiveFullAccess permissions in the IAM role, also CORS on the server.  But I can't work out how to enable CORS on the MediaLive API service.  API Gateway, incidentally, does not list MediaLive as a service it can connect to.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the simple test code producing the CORS errors above:

```
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1'; 
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:123456'});
    
    var medialive = new AWS.MediaLive({apiVersion: '2017-10-14'});
    
    var params = {
      InputSecurityGroupId: '123456' /* required */
    };
    medialive.describeInputSecurityGroup(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS is currently not supported by AWS MediaLive.

Given that calls from the browser using the Javascript SDK to the AWS Elemental MediaLive service will be cross-domain and the service doesn't support CORS, the browser will not allow this request to be made. A possible solution is to create a proxy on your domain that can proxy the request from the browser to MediaLive (and signing/auth the request in the proxy). This will prevent the request from appearing to be a cross-domain request.

Also, it is worth noting that using the Javascript SDK from the browser may create a security risk because the API keys would need to be in browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this!  

AWS JavaScript SDK does, however, support MediaLive API communication.  So could you please help me understand how to issue MediaLive commands from the browser and sidestep this CORS issue?  

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Mohammed, just checking if you have any further advice please?  

MediaLive does have an API library within the JavaScript SDK: so how does one communicate with it from the browser, without encountering these CORS issues?

Thank you!